# Power factor requirement for SMPS just above 75W

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, power-factor-correction

What is the power factor (PF) requirement for an SMPS or even just a standalone power factor correction (PFC) stage with a power level above 75W?

I know that in some cases the customer will specify the requirements at say 10% total rated load to be 0.9. For instance, assume that the PFC is rated for 1600W, thus 10% load will be 160W and the required PF is 0.9.

What about PF in between 75W - 160W? Does it have to comply with any requirements?

NOTE: Active power factor correction is considered in this example.

Comment: Are you referring to CE requirements?

Comment: Yes, it would have to be.

Comment: Then specify in the question what standards you require. The answer is probably in the standard anyways.

Comment: There is no information online about it (based on my research). In addition, to view a full standard you must purchase it I think.

Answer (score 1):

> *What about PF in between 75W - 160W? Does it have to comply with any
> requirements?*

From [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switched-mode_power_supply#Power_factor) and take particular note of the final sentence: -

> **In 2001, the European Union put into effect the standard
> IEC/EN61000-3-2 to set limits on the harmonics of the AC input current
> up to the 40th harmonic for equipment above 75 W. The standard defines
> four classes of equipment depending on its type and current waveform.
> The most rigorous limits (class D) are established for personal
> computers, computer monitors, and TV receivers. To comply with these
> requirements, modern switched-mode power supplies normally include an
> additional power factor correction (PFC) stage.**

If you dig around you can find tables like this: -

[image]

[Source document](https://www.emcfastpass.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Class_definitions.pdf) that has the above table and other good information on this subject.

Here's [another good bit](https://www.emcstandards.co.uk/files/61000-3-2_mains_harmonics.pdf) of reading material. And, [another useful link](https://emcfastpass.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Applicability_flow_chart.pdf).